# View for creating users mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create view(s) for administrating users in a MVC 5 app using the Aspnet membership tables. Are there any examples of doing this? I am completely new to MVC, coming from web forms ;)

Thanks!

Comment: The [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net) site has an entire section on [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) that includes dozens of tutorials and videos. One of the categories is [Security](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security). Any particular reason why you want to use ASP.NET membership instead of ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: I read most of them, I googled the subject and got some off topic articles. I am using whichever one comes with an MVC 5 project, AspNetRoles, AspNetUsers tables etc.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use and install this in order to have full basic control on your identity 2: [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples)
It install controllers, views and so on (global.asax, ...) so make attention, that will erase some files and the namespace of all the controllers is "AspnetIdentitySample".

Before installing it / instread of installing it, there is a github with that nuget package [nuget here](https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample/tree/master/AspnetIdentitySample). You can see how he made the controllers; views and so on.

Comment: cool, you will quickly understand MVC with those examples, it is quite well coded and that uses ViewBag, MVC and data binding, a quick start for you :-)

Comment: I am trying to add this functionality to my project, im struggling with adding the Role and User Controllers, i dont see which Data Context it's using.